# Override grails GORM methods (save, update delete)

Tags: grails, grails-orm, datasource

My Line Manager insists I use a REST based call to implement my persistence layer(which uses stored procedures) which I have done because he has a belief that hibernates doesn't scale well for performance(which I debated with him to no avail). I now want to override grails GORM methods(save, update, delete....) or better still, implement a REST data source. Anyone with any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GORM objects can be exposed as REST resources, by simply annotating as defined here:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#domainResources

But in your case, I would suggest you call stored procedures within service classes. You can get reference to the database connection, by injecting a dataSource.

You can then call these service methods, in a controller, which can extend a RESTController. Please refer to the following [link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restfulControllers).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but their is already another application that implements the rest, for instance if I want to save Address, I just have to call http://domain/address/save/?liine1=namehere

how do you think I can do this?